# Enable API for Customer Community user

Tags: api, customer-community

Is it possible to enable API for a Customer Community user? Use case is to use 3rd part application to enter data into Leads, Accounts etc.
I see the enable API in the Customer Community Login user profile but I cannot enable it. Any suggestion very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot modify standard profiles directly .The common practice here is to clone the standard profile .Cloning will allow you to do API enablement .

With customer community login you still won't be able to create accounts .only customer community plus user licence will allow you to create accounts

For leads I would suggest you to use web to lead feature .